# How to add an ul element custom event with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a draggable pair of lists. The design: 2 **ul** list, interchangable items, with drag and drop.

I am using  jquery sortable widget.

The question is that i want to fire an event when an **li** item drops in the  or fire some event when **ul** list change.

How can i do that??

HTML:

```
div class="col-lg-4">
<div class="form-group">
  <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
  }).disableSelection();
})
```

Comment: Add a 'drop: function(){}' after your connectWith property.

Comment: 'drop' is for 'droppable', 'stop' is for 'sortable', my bad.

Comment: if you don't know, please do not comment. @rsn

Comment: Sorry to get two seemingly similar jQuery UI interactions mixed up. See for yourself, buddy.. https://jsfiddle.net/0yw43n6w/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below snippet. Used stop and receive two events. Stop event will trigger every time element dragged and dropped. And receive event will trigger only when element is moved from one list to another.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      var dropElemTxt = $(ui.item).text();
      alert(dropElemTxt+" moved");
    },
    receive: function(event, ui) { 
      var dropElemTxt = $(ui.item).text();
      alert(dropElemTxt+" Moved from another list");
    },
  }).disableSelection();
})
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="form-group">
    <ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
      <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's great.. :)

Comment: with "stop" event it was enough to solved my problem   (y)

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to my comment above, use 'stop' instead of 'drop':

```
$(function() {
  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    stop: function(){
      alert("yeah buddy");
    }
  }).disableSelection();
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0yw43n6w/